# Makefile as simlink: not found

Tags: linux, macos, makefile

Is it possible to have a **Makefile** referenced by a **simlink**, and try calling action using **make**?

I am experiencing that calling make in a directory where Makefile is a simlink, Makefile is not found.

I have a need to reduce replication of Makefiles, and I would prefer using simlinks.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just fine:

```
test/
├── Makefile
└── mylink -> Makefile
cd test
make -f mylink
Hello
cat mylink
all:
        @echo "Hello"
```

Comment: Actually, it was a mistake in my end. Wrong symlink path.